# Calendário datepicker bootstrap com erro no ano bisexto

Tags: html, css, datepicker, bootstrap

Estou utilizando o `datepicker` do bootstrap, e constatei que o calendário de 2016 está errado. Hoje por exemplo é dia 01/07/2016 sexta feira e o calendário está exibindo como se fosse sábado. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe me dizer se existe alguma solução para resolver esse problema?

Javascript

```
$('#data_venda').datepicker({language: 'pt-br'});
```

tradução

```
;(function($){
    $.fn.datepicker.dates['pt-BR'] = {
        days: ["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado"],
        daysShort: ["Dom", "Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", "Sex", "Sáb"],
        daysMin: ["Do", "Se", "Te", "Qu", "Qu", "Se", "Sa"],
        months: ["Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"],
        monthsShort: ["Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez"],
        today: "Hoje",
        monthsTitle: "Meses",
        clear: "Limpar",
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Pode postar o link do site do componente, a versão que está usando e como está a configuração? Eu utilizo [este daqui](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io) e está normal.

Comment: Estou utilizando esse ai mesmo. Vou colocar o código na pergunta

Comment: Estranho o seu começar pela segunda. Acho que seu problema é apenas a ordem do daysMin no calendário mostrado, pois o normal é começar pelo domingo.

Comment: Somente com `$('#data_venda').datepicker();` fica dessa forma?

Comment: Verificamos que tem algo errado com a tradução que faz ocorrer isto. Mas ainda não resolvemos.

Comment: Qual a versão que você está utilizando? Poderia criar um fiddle para eu poder ver?

Comment: Nos arquivos não está especificado a versão. Mas acabei de resolver aqui. Foi a coisa mais boba

Comment: Poste a resposta para a galera mesmo assim, vai que outros também passam por essa coisa boba?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Após diversos testes foi identificado que o problema estava na tradução do calendário fazendo com que inicie a contagem na segunda feira. O que foi feito para resolver:

Na linha da tradução onde é especificado:

```
$.fn.datepicker.dates['pt-BR']
```

Alterei para `$.fn.datepicker.dates['pt-br']`

Por algum motivo que desconheço ao colocar o br em caixa alta estava traduzindo mas fazendo a contagem dos dias errados. Após colocar br minusculo passou a exibir o calendário corretamente como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então a tradução ficou dessa forma:

```
;(function($){
    $.fn.datepicker.dates['pt-br'] = {
        days: ["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado"],
        daysShort: ["Dom", "Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", "Sex", "Sáb"],
        daysMin: ["Dom", "Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", "Sex", "Sab"],
        months: ["Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"],
        monthsShort: ["Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez"],
        today: "Hoje",
        monthsTitle: "Meses",
        clear: "Limpar",
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
    };
}(jQuery));
```